# React Camera component does not work on mobile device

Tags: reactjs, camera, localhost, android-camera, webcam

I'm trying to test the Camera component on my react application using mobile devices (I tried with iPad pro and Google pixel 6a). I tried [react-webcam](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-webcam) and [react-camera-pro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-camera-pro), but neither works on mobile devices for some reason. (I used Google Chrome for the browser) For react-camera-pro, it gives me noCameraAccessible error, which clearly should not be true. I believe the problem is not related to permission because I can open the [demo](https://purple-technology.github.io/react-camera-pro/) for react-camera-pro, and the camera works perfectly fine. Has anyone experienced similar problems? If anyone knows the solution, can you please share the knowledge? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in testing environment you need to add `HTTPS=true` to your start script in `package.json`,i.e. `"HTTPS=true react-scripts start"`